# can't find method in react native component class

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am new to react native and playing with their methods. I have declared `albumCards` method but Its giving me issues during runtime.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, ScrollView, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './albumDetail';

class AlbumList extends Component {
  state = { albums : [] };

  albumCards() {
    return this.state.albums.map(album =>
      <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album}/>
    );
  }

  renderAlbums() {
    if (this.state.albums.length > 0) {
      return <ScrollView> { albumCards() } </ScrollView>
    } else {
      return  <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <View style = {styles.containerStyle}>
        {this.renderAlbums()}
      </View>
    );
  };
}


export default AlbumList;
```

I am getting the below error in the screenshot as albumscards could not be found. Could anyone please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call function like this.

```
<ScrollView> { this.albumCards } </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am still getting the error as Text Strings must be rendered within a Text Component

Comment: @AnilKothari please check the albumDetail component aswell. In React Native you cannot render any text outside of a <Text> tag.